# Fastest way to generate bit permutations in Python 3.x

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, binary, combinations

I need to generate all possible N choose K N-bit numbers where K bits are set.
The best and most concise option that I was able to come up with is extremely slow:

```
def kbits(n, k):
    result = set()
    for bits in itertools.combinations(range(n), k):
        s = 0
        for bit in bits:
            s |= 1 << bit
        result.add(s)
    return result
```

`kbits(25, 12)` took 8.3s on my machine.

How can I make it faster? For example, maybe there is a way to set all the bits in bulk, without looping through all of them?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with the result of this? What performance requirements do you have?

Comment: well, it's a part of solving traveling salesman problem using DP. I'm generating all 2**(n-1) subsets of the cities and then loop through them. Actually there are no performance requirements imposed on me apart from making it as fast as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `kbits(25, 12)` is calculating 12 of the same 25 powers of 2 more than five million times, when it only needs to calculate each of them once (and having done so, can use the `sum()` builtin rather than building results piecemeal).

Here's a much shorter solution, which is also about 3x faster on my machine:

```
def kbits(n, k):
    powers = [1 << e for e in range(n)]
    return {sum(bits) for bits in itertools.combinations(powers, k)}
```